# Internet filter for Mac OS

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to make an internet filter for Mac OS (10.6).  I've figured out the whole process (I'm a somewhat experienced Xcode developer), but I can't seem to find any info on how to catch an outgoing HTTP request.

Basically, I need some sort of method whose signature looks something like this:

```
-(BOOL)MacOSAppWillMakeHTTPRequest:(NSDictionary*(or something???))requestInfo
```

which will recieve information about the HTTP request being sent (particularly the URL) and can allow or block that request from being proccessed.

I've been searching through Apple's docs without finding anything of interest, except for kernel extensions, which seems a bit too extreme for this project.

Any ideas, suggestions, etc. are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Mac OS doesn't make HTTP requests, Mac OS merely opens TCP connections. It's up to the browser to make the request. (Not withstanding HTTP requests made using the URL loading system, but web browsers are unlikely to use that.) Exactly what part of "the whole process" have you actually figured out?

Comment: (For what it's worth, I doubt you can achieve this without kexts at all.)

Comment: I didn't mean it literally when I said Mac OS making HTTP requests, I just meant that I need to be able to intercept any HTTP request made by a Mac OS App and block or allow it. I will edit my question accordingly, as I see the confusion here.

Comment: My point is that you'll still likely have to code a huge chunk more than you think you will. One approach that comes to mind is creating a [socket filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/NKEConceptual/socket_nke/socket_nke.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001858-CH228-SW1), which will catch *any* connection. You'll use the filter to intercept data from the connection, and parse this data to determine if it's HTTP and what domain belongs to the IP address. You'll also have to decide how you want to "block" a request – break a connection, return an error page

Comment: Apple does not provide such notification. You need to implement it yourself, which is a LOT of work. [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) uses multiple kernel extensions (.kext) to achieve what you're looking for. Unless you have extensive experience in kernel extensions and programming in general, don't waste your time trying.

Comment: Wish I could -1 a comment. "[if you don't know how], don't waste your time trying" is rather poor advice. "...you have a lot of reading to do. Here're some resources to get you started..." would be a better way to finish your otherwise helpful comment.

Comment: Couldn't this basically be done with a local HTTP proxy server, without the need to create a kext?

Comment: @omz Depends on how difficult you want to make it to circumvent the filter. Just locking regular browsers into a proxy might not be doable on OS X, much less every app that uses HTTP.